# Strange fast growing mushroom like entity

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found this in my lounge today.
This room was cleaned less than 48hours ago, with no sign of this growth.

We sweeped and mopped, using the same floor cleaner we always do.

The two images below is of the same corner, but with the growth lifted in one image.

The consistency is like a fungus or mushroom and can probably be removed from the wall as one piece without much effort.

One of the walls close by do suffer from damp on occasion, but we have been in this house for over two years and have not had anything like this appear.

Please help!

[image][image]

Comment: How weird. Could it be leaking insulation foam or sealant or something? What makes you think it's fungal?

Comment: The way it's spreading looks like dry rot (Serpula lacrymans, Meruliporia incrassata or Fibroporia vaillantii), but the color doesn't look quite right. Did it stay that color or go darker at the center?

Comment: It is/was dry rot. The pictures were taken when these "flowers" just appeared, so it hasn't yet opened to show the orange/brown spores.

Comment: Builders have been in and ripped it all out, including our 100-year-old floorboards and fireplace :(

It is what it is... Thanks for the assistance though!

Comment: @Lizzie or Johan: please write up an answer so that this question can be marked as such. Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist Done!

Answer (score 3):

This is [dry rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_rot). It could be one of several species, including *Serpula lacrymans*, *Meruliporia incrassata* and *Fibroporia vaillantii*. It is a fungus that feeds on and decomposes wood. Despite the name, some moisture is required for growth, so 
it makes sense that your wall suffered from damp. The fruiting body will darken at the center as the spores appear.

Example images of dry rot fruiting bodies:

[image: dry rot image by Seabrooke Leckie]

[Photo by Seabrooke Leckie](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rustyblackbird/4756192862)

[image: dry rot image by Dave Brown]

[Photo by Dave Brown](https://www.flickr.com/photos/halide_art/2452065969)